# upload image from ios swift 3 to jsp web service

Tags: ios, json, jsp, jakarta-ee, swift3

hey I want to upload image from IOS (swift3) to JSP web service and save the image in web service  storage (will be better if in web-inf) and the path to mysql database anyone can help me with this or send me an example for that

thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

For the Swift part, the usual way to do it is to convert your image to a base64String

```
let image = UIImage(named:"test")

// Convert to PNG if you need lossless
if let pngBase64String = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.base64EncodedString() {
   // upload pngBase64String to server         
}

// or Convert to JPG        
let jpegCompressionQuality: CGFloat = 0.9
if let jpgBase64String = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, jpegCompressionQuality)?.base64EncodedString() {
    // Upload jpgBase64String to server
}
```

Comment: thanks i know that but i want the whole package iphone side and server side